# How do I get a SessionScoped CDI bean from inside a Filter?

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters, cdi

This question is related to a previous one on [writing a session timeout handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796612/what-is-the-method-for-gracefully-handling-session-timeout).

The answer in that thread involved accessing various session-scoped managed beans from the servlet.  The recommendation (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883430/prevent-accessing-restricted-page-without-login-in-jsf2)) is to do this in the filter:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
User user = (session != null) ? (User) session.getAttribute("user") : null;
```

Presumably this fetches a session bean of class **User**.  The problem is this doesn't work.

What goes wrong are that the beans are there in the session attributes, but they are wrapped by Weld facilities. I wrote the **doFilter()** method as follows:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    String sp = req.getServletPath();
    System.out.println("------------------------");
    System.out.println("doFilter(): " + sp);

    if (!sp.startsWith("/javax")) {  // eliminates many requests
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        Enumeration<String> en = session.getAttributeNames();
        int count = 0;            
        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
            String e = en.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Attribute " + ++count + ": " + e);
        }
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

When this dumps out the session attributes, I typically get something like this:

```
INFO: ------------------------
INFO: doFilter(): /Display.xhtml
INFO: Attribute 1: org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext#org.jboss.weld.bean-WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-extcdi-bundle-jsf20-1.0.1-ManagedBean-class org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf.impl.scope.conversation.EditableWindowContextManagerProxy
INFO: Attribute 2: org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpSessionContext#org.jboss.weld.bean-MyApp5-ManagedBean-class com.app.Login
INFO: Attribute 3: org.jboss.weld.context.conversation.ConversationIdGenerator
INFO: Attribute 4: com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap
INFO: Attribute 5: org.jboss.weld.context.ConversationContext.conversations
INFO: Attribute 6: facelets.ui.DebugOutput
INFO: Attribute 7: javax.faces.request.charset
INFO: Attribute 8: org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.core.api.scope.conversation.WindowContext:EXISTING_WINDOW_ID_LIST
```

Attribute #2 seems to represent the bean that I want.  Needless to say a call to **session.getAttribute("login")** doesn't work.

Can anyone say how to access the underlying managed bean?  I would prefer to do it in a way that was not tied to Weld, but that may not be possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This approach works for session scoped JSF `@ManagedBean` only, not for CDI `@Named` bean.

You need to [`@Inject`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Inject.html) it as a property of the filter.

```
@Inject
private User user;
```

Comment: BalusC do you ever sleep?  I just tried annotating my filter with **`@Named`** and doing an **`@Inject`** of my **Login** bean.  It worked!  I had no idea that the CDI service would work in a **Filter**.  I suppose this means that the **Filter** object is instantiated for each request cycle, not just once for the Servlet's lifetime.

Comment: It's only 21:02 right now :) It should just work if you annotate the filter with `@WebFilter`. I'd rather not make it `@Named` (similarly, `@Inject` should work in `@WebServlet` servlets as well). The CDI is more a proxy. The objects are injected on a threadlocal basis, the to-be-injected instance doesn't need to be of the same or a broader scope.

Comment: @BalusC: Is this solution thread safe as `user` become a member var of the filter?

Comment: @Toru: only if you don't omit `@Inject`.

Comment: @BalusC you are one of a kind

Answer (score 5):

```
import org.jboss.weld.context.SerializableContextualInstanceImpl;

    HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) facesContext.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    Enumeration<String> attribs = httpSession.getAttributeNames();
    String attrib = null;
    while (attribs.hasMoreElements()) {         
        attrib = attribs.nextElement();
        Object obj = httpSession.getAttribute(attrib);
        if(obj instanceof SerializableContextualInstanceImpl){
            SerializableContextualInstanceImpl impl = (SerializableContextualInstanceImpl)obj;
            //here: MyObject myObj= (MyObject)impl.getInstance();
        }           
    }
```