# Overwriting injected object

Tags: java, jboss, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm a little bit confused about the CDI-behavior regarding the changing of injected objects.

I've got a simple user-class containing login and password. I produce an object for CDI:

```
public class SessionService {

    @LoggedIn
    @Produces @SessionScoped
    public User loggedInUser() {
        return new User("login", "pass");
    }
}
```

In the next step, the user opens an login-view and the login-controller checks the credentials.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class LoginController extends Controller implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6047784887724513434L;

    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @Inject
    Credentials credentials;

    @Inject
    @LoggedIn
    User currentUser;

    public void doLogin() {
        User check = userService.findUser(credentials.getLogin());
        if((check != null) && (check.getPasswort().equals(SHA256.hash(credentials.getPasswort())))) {
            currentUser = check;
            FacesRedirect.fromOutcome("login.success");
        } else {
            addErrorMessage("loginFailed");
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to overwrite the initially produced currentUser-object with the found "check"-user this doesn't work - I don't get an error, but the injected object in other classes is the same as before.
When I call the setLogin() / setPassword() methods of the injected currentUser-object, these changes are available to all other classes.

```
currentUser.setId(check.getId());
currentUser.setLogin(check.getLogin());
currentUser.setPasswort(check.getPassword());
```

Is there another way to overwrite the whole object instead of calling all the setters?

On the first try I used @Produces in the LoginController, but when I what to inject it into an Filter, the startup fails.

Thanks for the help,
Tobias

==================== edit ====================

Like @atamanroman suggested, I removed the SessionService and added this to the LoginController:

```
@Produces
@LoggedIn
public User getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}
```

I use `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` for the controllers SessionScope, the LoginFilter looks like this:

```
package de.mad_onion.thweb.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import de.mad_onion.thweb.domain.User;

@Named("loginFilter")
@WebFilter(filterName = "LoginFilter", urlPatterns = {"/einsatz.xhtml"})
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    @LoggedIn
    User currentUser;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession();

        if(currentUser == null) {
            System.out.println("No user");
        } else {
            System.out.println("User:");
            System.out.println(currentUser.toString());
        }
        fc.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("Filter initialized");
    }
}
```

If I try to deploy the application, I get this stacktrace:

```
18:03:47,025 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/thweb]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception starting filter LoginFilter: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011048: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:85) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator$1.<init>(WebComponentInstantiator.java:57) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.component.WebComponentInstantiator.getReference(WebComponentInstantiator.java:55) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.instantiate(WebInjectionContainer.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:78) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:441) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:3269) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3865) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:598) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:616) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractReceiverBean.getReceiver(AbstractReceiverBean.java:73) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ProducerMethod$1.produce(ProducerMethod.java:131) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:299) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:61) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:616) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:681) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.InjectableField.inject(InjectableField.java:56) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldEEInjection.inject(WeldEEInjection.java:81) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.injection.WeldInjectionInterceptor.processInvocation(WeldInjectionInterceptor.java:60) [jboss-as-weld-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceInterceptorFactory.java:95) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 15 more

18:03:47,095 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error filterStart
18:03:47,097 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/thweb] startup failed due to previous errors
18:03:47,100 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./thweb: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./thweb: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]

18:03:47,313 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "thweb.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./thweb" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./thweb: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
18:03:47,319 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS011005: Failed to destroy component instance org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstance@cafb6f: org.agoncal.application.petstore.exception.ValidationException: Category object is null
    at org.agoncal.application.petstore.service.CatalogService.removeCategory(CatalogService.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:374) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:81)
    at org.agoncal.application.petstore.util.LoggingInterceptor.logMethod(LoggingInterceptor.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocation$InterceptorMethodInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:72)
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:71)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:112)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:135)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:202)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.agoncal.application.petstore.service.CatalogService$$$view127.removeCategory(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:264)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:111)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:105)
    at org.agoncal.application.petstore.service.CatalogService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.removeCategory(CatalogService$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at de.mad_onion.thweb.service.DBPopulator.clearDB(DBPopulator.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptorFactory.java:130) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceReleaseInterceptorFactory.java:90) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:333)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonLifecycleCMTTxInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponentInstance.destroy(BasicComponentInstance.java:119) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.destroySingletonInstance(SingletonComponent.java:179)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponent.stop(SingletonComponent.java:136)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentStartService.stop(ComponentStartService.java:49) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.stopService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1911) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StopTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1874) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
```

Comment: How do you inject the current user in the other classes? If they get it from your LoginController, overwriting the user object should be fine if they get it AFTER the login.

Comment: I simply inject it via `@Inject @LoggedIn User currentUser;`. The view is also called after login but it doesn't work as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you inject your current User in other beans with `@Inject @LoggedIn` the container will always call the method annotated with @Producer and alas create a new User (`return new User("login", "pass");`). The correct User will only be set in your LoginController, which has nothing at all to do with your SessionService. I guess removing SessionService and creating a getter for `currentUser` in `LoginController` which is marked with `@Produces @LoggedIn` will solve the problem in your logic.

**The real problem seems to be that injection into your Filter does not work.** Could you please verify that you use the correct @SessionScoped annotation (not from jsf) and show your filter implementation with a detailed error message?

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815308/how-do-i-get-a-sessionscoped-cdi-bean-from-inside-a-filter), you have to annotate your Filter class with @WebFilter/@Named instead of @ManagedBean or @Inject won't work. Mixing both may cause unwanted headache.

Comment: I'm not sure if `@WebServlet` and `@Named` work together. `@WebServlet` should be sufficient. Have you tried injecting the `LoginController` directly into the servlet and call the getter from there?

Comment: I removed @Named, same exception as before. Now I inject LoginController directly and call the getCurrentUser()-method and everything works like a charm...

Comment: I forgit to mention that this still isn't the way I'd like to implement it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of "fancy" ways to do this, but honestly, using the setters is the cleanest way to do this.