# How do I get a ConversationScoped CDI bean from inside a Filter?

Tags: java, cdi, servlet-filters, conversation-scope

Getting a `@SessionScoped` CDI bean from inside a Filter is [relatively easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815308/how-do-i-get-a-sessionscoped-cdi-bean-from-inside-a-filter). But trying to inject a `@ConversationScoped` bean throws the following error:

```
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException:
WELD-001303 No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped
```

This is independent of whether or not a conversation is currently active. It seems like CDI can not determine whether a transient or active conversation should be used because my filter happens before whatever provides the context for `@ConversationScoped` beans.

What kind of filter / interception mechanism could be used that happens "late enough"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how other implementations do this, but at least Weld uses a Filter itself to handle conversations, so your filter would need to be after that one in the filter chain.

Comment: Since there seems to be no satisfying solution to the problem, I'll accept your answer.