# Session management functionality in jsf project

Tags: session, jsf

i am a beginner programmer and want to know how session management and login logout functionality can be incorporated in jsf project. Right now i can authenticate users from a table in the database but giving the direct url of the pages in the browser takes any anonymous user to the requested page of mine. i want only authenticated users to access the pages while their sessions are active. how is this done and what exactly i need to study to get this functionality in my application.

bundles of thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent accessing restricted page without login in Jsf2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883430/prevent-accessing-restricted-page-without-login-in-jsf2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. There was a statement in my HibernateUtils class
     `session.close` which was commented out and this is now working as expected after removing this comment.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at something like Seam Security: http://seamframework.org/Seam3/SecurityModule